# Regular expression needed for matching words inside "{" braces

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which would match below words in a string or text:

```
{=rankedArea?metricType=3902&area={parent-area-identifier}:AdministrativeWard}
{=compare?metricType=3281&area={child-area-identifier}&with={parent-area-identifier}&period=cal_2011&greater=greater than&equal=equal to&less=less than} 
{district-short-label} 
{child-area-short-label} 
{authority-area-short-label}
```

Basically, it should match a word starting with "{" and the word ending with "}", however it should also consider similar words in between i.e.

```
{=compare?metricType=3281&area={child-area-identifier}&with={parent-area-identifier}&period=cal_2011&greater=greater than&equal=equal to&less=less than}
```

In the expression above, it should also consider `{parent-area-identifier}` and should match the expression mentioned above.

Comment: Use `{.*?}` or `{[^}]*}`

Comment: Not working. Tried on http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to worry about *arbitrary* nesting of `{...}`, you can write:

```
[{](?:[^{}]+|[{][^{}]*[}])*[}]
```

Comment: Excellent!! Works perfectly. Thanks a ton.

Comment: The simpler [`{([^{}]+)}`](https://regex101.com/r/lK6xC7/1) would do the job as well.

Comment: @Jan: That regex doesn't match the OP's first, second, and last examples. (I suspect that you're simply misunderstanding what the OP is asking for. Admittedly, the question was worded confusingly, but given that the OP says my regex "works perfectly", my interpretation is apparently the correct one.)

Comment: @ruakh: No complaints about your solution :-) Admittedly, I thought he was looking for `parent-area-identifier` in the first and `child-area-identifier` in the second example but perhaps I did not get the question well. Anyway, +1 for yours.

Comment: @NishitVaghela If recursion is available in your regex flavor, [try this](https://regex101.com/r/rT4wK5/1): `{(?>[^}{]|(?0))*}`

Comment: @bobblebubble thanks for replying. This isn't probably working on regexr.com. The solution given by ruakh works perfectly for me.